# How to center text vertically and horizontally in responsive container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I center text vertically and horizontally in responsive (bootstrap) container?
I've been playing around with various table and table-cell display methods, but cannot get anything to work correctly.

Here is the html, I'm trying to center the contents of the span tag over the image.

- I need the image to control the size of the container's height, without it the container just collapses to the height of the line.
- I cannot set a static height on the div>div>div either since it scales with the browser size/view.

### HTML

```
<div class="row  media-thumbs">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div>
            <span>Some copy should go here</span>
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="default-tile.gif">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### WORKING CODE

With Alexander's help/clues, I modified the plugin ( https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center )to get the correct width and height

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.flexVerticalCenter = function( onAttribute ) {

        return this.each(function(){

            var $this       = $(this);              // store the object
            //var attribute = onAttribute || 'margin-top'; // the attribute to put the calculated value on
                //alert($this.css('padding-top'));
            // recalculate the distance to the top of the element to keep it centered
            var resizer = function () {
                // get parent height minus own height and devide by 2
                $this.css({
                    'margin-top' : ((( $this.parent().height() - $this.height() ) / 2) - parseInt($this.css('padding-top')) ),
                    'width' : ($this.parent().width())
                });
            };

            // Call once to set.
            resizer();

            // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
            $(window).resize(resizer);

            // Apply a load event to images within the element so it fires again after an image is loaded
            $this.find('img').load(resizer);

        });

    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: For vertical centering, try this plugin: it's really simple and easy to implement. https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center

Comment: Hmm, it's not working because it is in the same container as the image.

Comment: If the container around the image is the same height as the image, shouldn't it work?  Perhaps make the span a display: block; and set the jQuery plugin to vertically center by using padding-top.  Let me make sure I'm getting what you want to do correctly;  something like the second box of [this](http://citycafescranton.com/) website, how the text is vertically and horizontally centered responsively?

Comment: Actually I just did a bit of tinkering with the plugin, it seems to require that the parent element has a set height. However, maybe the real solution here is to write my own jquery plugin [or find one ;)]

Comment: Huh, I thought the containing element would be set to the same height as the image, or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: *edit: I think I figured out what you mean.  Is it possible to use a background image instead of an image element?

Comment: Unfortunately, no on the background image. the image is what is forcing the container div to be of a certain height. which varies with screen size. :(

Comment: I think I might have got something to the same effect as what you were asking.  Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/QaKgy/1/

Comment: It does work, I found the issue. the height of the parent div is not set until after the page is completely loaded [it appears] placing the code in the  $(window).load(function(){ solves this neatly.

Comment: oh good!  I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/QaKgy/3/)

**Explanation:**

*CSS*:

```
span
{
    position: absolute;  /* this makes the text able to be placed over the image without getting pushed over */
    width: 100%; /*set to 100% so text-align will fall in the center of the image*/
    text-align: center; /*text will be horizontally centered in the image*/
    color: white; /*purely aesthetic*/
}

img
{
    width: 100%;   /* The image is set to 100% to take up the container and be responsive */ 
}
```

*Javascript*:

I used a jQuery plugin called [Flex Vertical Center](https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center) ([also available in vanilla javascript](https://github.com/devmatt/js-flex-vertical-align)) to vertically center the `<span>`, as CSS can be impossibly bothersome.
After including the javascript source in the HTML, the following code was simple call to the function:

```
$('span').flexVerticalCenter();
```

Comment: Almost, I updated the plugin a little myself as the width 100% forces the div to be as wide as the column container. Plugin code added to my question.

Comment: Omg at last an instant solution for this horrible problem. I will totally use it every single time I come across vertical centering! Thanks!!

Comment: Note to future readers: please consider using FlexBox instead!

Answer (score -1):

Use `text-align: center` to center horizontally and you can try `vertical-align: middle` (thought there are a few gotchas with vertical alignment), or set a `line-height` equal to the parent container height.

Comment: We don't know the parent container height at any given view. it's dynamic.

Comment: Would using a `margin-top: something%;` work for the text? If you're using `box-sizing: border-box` and you know the height the text it's fairly easy to center.

Comment: margin-top would help, but starts to cause problems when the copy is one or more lines.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on outer elements styles, a very effective method is `margin: 0 auto;` for elements you want to set horizontally centered.
This method requires a defined width of the parent element.
`text-align:center;` will work in most cases, as told Sean, but `vertical-align:middle;` needs a lot of css-work to the parent element. I try not to use this, it never works as expected, from scratch :-) I remember, if the parent element is set to a defined height and `display:table-cell;` it works, otherwise not.